# Is it possible to reach terminal velocity on the ground?

Tags: forces, terminology, velocity

If your running from a giant fan (or anything else that can pull laterally) and running at the same speed your pulled, would that count as terminal velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) states that terminal velocity is achieved when the downward gravity and the upward drag force and bouyancy cancel out, giving the object effectively zero acceleration.

I think you can "rotate" this situation to describe e.g. a rocket sled that drives on a very wide plane. Terminal velocity would then be achieved if the acceleration can't overcome the drag force anymore (since buoyancy and gravity fall out of the equation in this scenario).

We can use the drag equation
$$
F_D = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_D A
$$
and set the left-hand side equal to $m \cdot a$ for a given acceleration. However, considering that (military) airplanes can fly at supersonic speeds easily, I think it's not really useful to apply the concept to this question. Plus, as DilithiumMatrix has mentioned, it's somewhat defined as the velocity achievable solely by falling in a fluid.

Comment: pretty nice explanation John W

Answer (score 1):

The definition on [Wikipedia Terminal Velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) is

> Terminal velocity is the highest velocity attainable by an object as it falls through a fluid (air is the most common example, but the concept applies equally to any fluid). It occurs when the sum of the drag force (Fd) and the buoyancy is equal to the downward force of gravity (FG) acting on speed that a freely falling object eventually reaches when the resistance of the medium through which it is falling prevents further acceleration.

Ok,  ignore the falling bit for a minute, but I think the difference is **also** you still have some leeway when running, because you are connected to a static surface,  over your horizontal velocity, but no control at all when you are completely immersed in a  fluid.

So both by definition and the situation you set up here, the answer is no, even if you modified the definition.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The term *'terminal velocity'* (as apposed to a general, situational *maximum*-velocity) specifically refers to the balance between gravitational force and drag (and possible buoyancy, depending on the situation).